# Webcam in a GCP Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter, webcam

I'm trying to do some live webcam video processing with a GCP Jupyter Notebook.
I've tried some solutions including the one below where I use openCV but openCV wont read it at all. 
I'm thinking the problem is getting the webcam video feed to stream into the virtual machine first which I can't figure out how to do.

Is there a widget for this?
P.S. Also tried ipywidgets ipywebrtc with no luck.

Reason i'm doing this is my laptop doesnt support CUDA which I need for my program.

```
import cv2
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import PIL.Image
from io import StringIO
import IPython.display
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML, Audio
from base64 import b64decode
import numpy as np
import io

VIDEO_HTML = """
<video autoplay
 width=%d height=%d style='cursor: pointer;'></video>
<script>

var video = document.querySelector('video')

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
  .then(stream=> video.srcObject = stream)

var data = new Promise(resolve=>{
  video.onclick = ()=>{
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    var [w,h] = [video.offsetWidth, video.offsetHeight]
    canvas.width = w
    canvas.height = h
    canvas.getContext('2d')
          .drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h)
    video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].stop()
    video.replaceWith(canvas)
    resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', %f))
  }
})
</script>
"""

#Code doesnt work
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(display(HTML(VIDEO_HTML % (256,256,0.8))))
cap1 = VideoRecorder(stream=display(HTML(VIDEO_HTML % (256,256,0.8))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is indeed how to get the webcam video feed to stream into the virtual machine. The GCP Jupyter Notebooks have a VM instance in its backend so the thing is how to transfer your video data stream to the backend VM.

To solve this issue you need to do two things:

The first one is a server in your computer that takes the video from the webcam. I found this github repo [1] to create a RTSP server.

The second one is to go into the VM instance in GCP and configure a RTSP client that listens your server port where the video is being sent. Then in your notebook you'll need to read this data coming from the server (your laptop).

There are other ways to do it, for example if your webcam is an IP camera (if it's not you can also do this) you can send the video over http, and by creating a http server in your virtual instance then you can push (I don't know if real-time) the video streaming there. I've been investigating if opencv has already implemented this but I'm not sure. I will search a bit more to check this.

Take in consideration that receiving live video from your webcam to an AI notebook will not be an easy task. Is it a must to have live video?

[1] https://github.com/revmischa/rtsp-server